# How can I add another .ibd file to my existing table when the memory space is full?

Tags: mariadb-10.3

I am working on an enterprise solution on MariaDB. The biggest challenge we are facing is to find a solution if our tablespace is full (.ibd file) and how can we add another .ibd file which will work like a joint memory space.

Considering we are using file_per_tablespace and MariaDB does not allow any DDM/DDL queries relating to tablespaces and datafiles.

Comment: What?  How can .ibd be full?  Because the _disk_ is full?  Or you have the disk partitioned, and the partition you are on is full?  More specifics, please.  And numbers.

Comment: Hello @RickJames,
I am a research intern working to migrate from oracle 11g to maria 10.3 
Like in oracle I can a data file in the same tablespace so that the file doesn't run out of memory. Similarly, I want maria to work or any alternative how to do it.

Comment: Oracle has a zillion features that almost no one ever needs.  Did you mean "memory" or "disk"?  How does the feature prevent running out of disk/memory?  Partitioning disks asks for trouble -- Space is available in one partition but needed in another.

Comment: You are new to Computer Science?  Precision in terminology is key to success.

Comment: Hi @RickJames, let me furnish you with a more specific straightforward question:

Can I add another datafile in the current table space ?

Comment: It is possible to `INSERT` more rows into an existing database table.  And it can be done with `INSERT` or `LOAD DATA INFILE` or a few other DML statements.

Comment: @RickJames You can check out this link where I posted the same query and I got a clear response.

Link: https://mariadb.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/118759-general/topic/MariaDB.2010.2E3.3A.20DataFiles

Comment: It would be nice if we did not have to create a login to see that link.

Answer (score 0):

You have the [table is full error](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/full-table.html)?

Check you are not out of disk space?

`innodb_file_per_tablespace` will affect tables newly created.

[ALTER TABLE xxx FORCE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/alter-table/) will cause the table to be recreated in its new tablespace and the old one removed.

Comment: Hi Dan, we want to keep our data not to be removed. When the table is full I want to link a new data file which can help me add more data to the table.

Comment: I don't know if there is a way. Creating a partition may work but test first and/or ask mariadb's enterprise support.

Comment: Thank you @danblack I have put up a question in MDB knowledge base from where I haven't heard till date.

Comment: also try https://mariadb.zulipchat.com. Also apologies for mixing up your use of enterprise and assuming it was part of the product name.

Comment: LoL. @danblack I feel like chasing a ghost. I don't know whether maria supports it or not.